# Why does the MacBook Pro show only 3GB of memory when 4GB is installed?

Tags: mac, memory

I've been using my MaBook Pro happily for months but only recently realized that 1 GB is missing. Is there something wrong with my MacBook? It seem to runs fine.

Comment: What MacOSX version? I have a very similar problem. Though I could access all the 4GB under MacOSX 10.5 -- I only have the problem since MacOSX 10.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually this is because you're using a 32-bit operating system rather than a 64-bit one.

UPDATE: [Apparently, this is a chipset limitation in the earlier Macbook Pros](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Apple/?p=321)

Comment: No - my wife's MBP can only address 3Gb, and mine can address 4Gb, and we're running exactly the same OS.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Good.  Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Which MBP?  My wife's 3 year old 15" MBP has a published maximum memory of 3Gb.  My 1.5 year old 17" MPB has a published maximum memory of 4Gb.